# iTunes search API not returning any values

Tags: ios, json, rest, itunes

I'm trying to build a `URL` to query the iTunes API to get `podcast` information.

I have tried using 
https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=podcast
and
https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=podcast

have also tried adding country and limit paramaters
https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=podcast&country=us
https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=podcast&limit=25

Currently I am just typing the URL into the browser (chrome) to see if I can get a `JSON` response, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Response I get:

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the url in private browsing? Could it be that some id cookie is missing in your app session, that your browser gets right ?

Comment: Just tried incognito on your suggestion. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the 'term' parameter which is a requirement.